# why does this raise a SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, copy, warnings

Working with pandas here in python.

Maybe I'm missing something but why would this raise a settingwithcopywarning?

```
cars['l_per_100km'] = (235.21/cars.mpg).round(2)
```

I'm getting

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

I don't think I'm chain indexing here somewhere, or do I?

Comment: The issue likely stems for a line of code a few rows above that. At that point is `cars` based off of some susbet of a larger DataFrame, i.e. do you do something like `cars = cars[some_Boolean_Series]` or `cars=cars.drop_duplicates()`. You should find the step like that that returns a `copy` of the DataFrame and add on a `.copy()` to ensure that pandas creates a new object.

Comment: on the money! I had this line a few lines above `cars = cars.loc[cars.origin != 'usa', :]`, I added .copy() there as you suggested, works perfectly and no warning, thx!